# What is different about the way IE implements last-child?

Tags: html, css

I am using a template that has CSS code looking like this:

```
h2:last-child,
p:last-child,
ul:last-child,
ol:last-child,
dl:last-child,
hr:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* IE class */
h2.last-child,
p.last-child,
ul.last-child,
ol.last-child,
dl.last-child,
hr.last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why the author did it differently for IE?  Is that still needed for the modern browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that there is/was a decorator JS library/code that adds the class `.last-child` and `.first-child` to what it is applied to for IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably using jQuery, to apply a class to the last child element because older IE browsers do not support css3 and thus `last-child` would not work.

```
$("hr:last-child")
    $(this).addClass("last-child");
});
```

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is a great library that helps conditionally handle js/css for different browsers